# Why: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: sh, configure, autoconf

In a configure file (#!/bin/sh/) generated by autoconf, there is a paragraph inside like the following:

```
if ac_fn_cxx_try_compile "$LINENO"; then :

        { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5
$as_echo "yes" >&6; }
    succeeded=yes
    found_system=yes

else


fi
```

And when I execute ./configure it tells me "syntax error near unexpected token `fi'" at that line. It is not the end of the file.

Comment: If you have nothing in `else` you get an error. Either `delete else` or put a `:` between `else` and `fi`. **and** get rid of the `:` after `then`.

Comment: You bet, I get caught by something simple all the time. If it solved the problem, you can select the Answer as correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In line with the comment:

```
if ac_fn_cxx_try_compile "$LINENO"; then

    $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: yes" >&5 
    $as_echo "yes" >&6;
    succeeded=yes
    found_system=yes

else

    ##  look nothing here !!
    ##  at least put a ':'
    ##  or delete else altogether

fi
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition, I have found why autoconf generates such configure file. I copied the configure.ac from Windows and it has ^M as return. Autoconf thinks ^M is something and add it into else...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error when compiling libtorrent with minGW.
The problem was a m4 macro saved as a DOS file. Converting "ax_boost_base.m4" to linux file endings did the trick.
I am almost sure I have misconfigured GIT on my windows: It converts all files to DOS which is no good idea.

Comment: Thank you so much.  You and @cbear1985 just saved me a lot of time; I was trying to build [libusb-compat](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/tree/master/mingw-w64-libusb-compat-git) in MSYS2, and I have enabled autocrlf in my git configuration, so those files had CRLF line endings when they got checked out during the build process.